# Trouble linking multiple object C files (using cmd, gcc, devcpp and windows)

Tags: c, gcc

I am working on an expression evaluator with 7 different C files, of which Test.c contains the  main function. Others perform functions like infix to postfix, check precendence and the like. I have separately compiled each .c file to generate the object files(.o). How do I link and execute them ? (I am using gcc, Dev Cpp IDE and windows 10) I used cmd to compile (gcc -c filename.c) but am unable to link and execute the files.

Comment: gcc -o outputfile file1.o file2.o file3.o...

Comment: does the order of linking matter?

Comment: No, the order of the *.o files doesn't matter, but the order of libraries (if any) matters. Just Google a bit, there are soo many tutorials out there about this. e.g. https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html

Comment: Thankyou ! I got exactly  what i was looking for.